# Unable to install timeshift in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: restore

I followed these steps to install timeshift:

1. sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
2. sudo apt-get update

then get this message:

```
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B5B116B72D0F61F0
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Is timeshift safe to download and use? If so how do I go about getting it?

Comment: "[H]ow to get timeshift" seems clearly explained at the source: https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I followed these instructions but got the reported error

Answer (score 2):

It's odd that apt-add-repository couldn't download the public key, as it *is* available. Does your network block port 11371? I think this is needed to fetch keys, which is what failed.
You can try adding it manually, run this command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 2D0F61F0
```

then repeat the apt-add-repository command you tried at the beginning, and it should now work because you have the key.

If this still fails, it's likely that as I mentioned your network is blocking the needed port to fetch the keys. In that case, speak to your network administrator and try to get this situation resolved on their side.